# Initialisation of weights for deeplearning model

Tags: deep-learning, variance

I am going through a book on deep learning which initializes weights between two layers of neurons as:

```
w = np.random.randn(layers[i] + 1, layers[i + 1] + 1)
self.W.append(w / np.sqrt(layers[i]))
```

As per the book, divison by np.sqrt(layers[i]) in second line of code is done for following reason:

> scale w by dividing by the square root of the number of nodes in the current layer, thereby
>   normalizing the variance of each neuron’s output

What does it exactly mean? And how would it impact if we don't do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weights initialization is very important to tackle the vanishing/Explosion Gradients. In order for the output/gradients(reverse direction) to flow properly, the **variance** of the outputs of each layer to be equal to the variance of its input. Likewise of gradients in the reverse direction. the input and output flow of a layer is called *fan-in* and *fan-out* of the layer.

To better explain what I mean above, let me give you an example. Assume that we have a hundred consecutive layers and we apply a feed forward calculation with linear activation (After all it is just matrix multiplication), the data is 500 samples of 100 features:

```
neurons, features = 100, 100
n_layers = 100

X = np.random.normal(size=(500, features))  # your input
mean, var = 0, 0
for layer in range(n_layers):
    W = np.random.normal(size=(features, neurons))
    X = np.dot(X, W)
    mean = mean + X.mean()
    var = var + X.var()
mean/n_layers, np.sqrt(var/n_layers)

# output:
(-4.055498760574568e+95, 8.424477240271639e+98)
```

You will see that it will have a huge mean and standard deviations. Lets break this problem down; a property of a matrix multiplication of which the result will have a standard deviation very close to the square root of the number of *fan in* (input) connections. This property can be verified with this snippet of code:

```
fan_in = 1000  # change it to any number

X = np.random.normal(size=(100, fan_in)) 
W = np.random.normal(size=(fan_in, 1))

np.dot(X, W).std()

# result:
32.764359213560454
```

This happens because we sum fan_in (1000 in the above case) products of the element-wise multiplication of one element of inputs X by one column of W. Therefore, if we scaled every weights by the *1/sqrt(fan_in)* to maintain the distribution of the flow as seen in the following snippet:

```
neurons, features = 100, 100
n_layers = 100

X = np.random.normal(size=(500, features))  # your input
mean, var = 0, 0
for layer in range(n_layers):
    W = np.random.normal(size=(features, neurons), scale=np.sqrt(1 / neurons))  # scaled the weights with the fan-in 
    X = np.dot(X, W)
    mean = mean + X.mean()
    var = var + X.var()
mean/n_layers, np.sqrt(var/n_layers)

# output:
(0.0002608301398189543, 1.021452570914829)
```

You can read more about kernel initialization in the following [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/weight-initialization-in-neural-networks-a-journey-from-the-basics-to-kaiming-954fb9b47c79)